# Response time for a message in IBM Websphere MQ

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I have integrated my .NET application with IBM WebSphere MQ.I am sending messages through MQ to a application. I am getting too much delayed reponse.I want to identify if the delay is caused by the receiving application or by the MQ itself. How I can calculate the elapsed time between request/response for a message in MQ?

Answer (score 0):

MQ can easily move 100 messages/second - it depends on the size/power of the server.

I seriously doubt MQ is the bottleneck.  What is the receiving application doing when it receives a message?

The simplest solution is to turn on COA & COD report options then send the message.

- COA (Confirmation on Arrival) will tell you when the message landed in the queue and was available for the receiving application.
- COD (Confirmation on Delivery) will tell you when the message was read (consumed) by the receiving application.

My guess is that you will find out that either (1) the receiving application does not read the message right away or (2) the receiving application takes a long time to do its actual work (before responding to your application).

Comment: How to get COA and COD from .NET client.I dont have any access to MQ. How I can isolate the problem from .NET client?

Comment: It is done in your .NET code.  Did you use Google to look up the information?  Go look up MQRO_COA and MQRO_COD in the MQ Knowledge Center.  Here is the link to MQMessage.NET class that explain it: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the COA and COD will provide me time when the message is reached in the Remote MQ and when it has been delivered to the destination application. But I want the total MQ time slice.Preferably the time when the destination application put the message into MQ and when it is delivered.

Comment: MQ is an Async message system (You are thinking Synchronous). You have everything you need. The COA time minus the message's PutTime is the total time MQ used to move & make the message available. COD time minus COA time is the time the message sat in the queue before the message was read by the receiving application. The response message's (from receiver) PutTime minus the COD time (from original message) is how long the receiving application took do their thing and I think this is what you are looking for.